# Find an abelian subgroup of $GL(2n, q)$ of special order

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, abelian-groups, symplectic-linear-algebra

I want to prove that $GL(2n, q)$ where $q$ is even, has an abelian subgroup of order $q^{2n - 1}$.  please help me.

Answer (score 3):

The matrices consisting of 1's on the main diagonal and 0's everywhere else except in the last column form an abelian subgroup of order $q^{2n-1}$.  In fact, if the last column (other than the 1 at the bottom) is treated as a vector, the multiplication operation is just addition of vectors.